# Is it possible for a git Client to have hosted repositories with different attributes?

Tags: git, attributes, config, repository

What I talk here is for ONE project in the workspace. I would like to setup a repository on my own PC with a specific attributes setup, and to use also a hosted repository with other attributes, especially including filtering.
So is it possible to have repositories with different attributes/configurations for the same project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes : if you specify the attributes in the `.git/info/attributes` file, they aren't commited and are thus specific to your own version of the repository.

Comment: No, I don't want a different version in my workspace, I want a repository (commit) on my workstation generated from some attributs settings that are defined in my worspace, and a hosted repository commited with different attributs, also defined in my workspace, but I would like to differentiate attributs sets depending on where I commit.

Comment: When you commit in your workspace, you commit locally. You can't do a distant commit. You *push* to a distant repository. But maybe I don't see what you try to do, I'll let other git users answer this one.

Comment: Thanks anyway for replying. Probably, I was not precise enough. Let say it an other way : I want to apply some filters to my local repository, and some others to the remote one.

Comment: In this case I don't see why my answer doesn't work for you : edit both `.git/info/attributes` files. But I'm sure I miss something.

Comment: Hum, after some mind checking, I think you are right. I will test it.